# Tailwind css break-word not working in input field

Tags: css, reactjs, tailwind-css

Now my reactjs input field looked like this.
[image: Input field for eventName]

As you can see the text just keeps going straight and not moving down to the next line. How do I solve this? Here is my code for this input field.

```
<input className="bg-slate-50 text-main-blue border border-gray-300 drop-shadow-lg text-sm rounded-md my-5 block w-full p-2.5 whitespace-normal word-break:break-word" type="text" name="eventName" placeholder="Event Name" required onChange={event => setEventName(event.target.value)} value={eventName}/>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Change `word-break:break-word` to `break-words`

*There is no class `word-break:break-word` in tailwind-css*

---

This is actually work of  `textarea` not `text`, Use `type = "textarea"` to get the desired result .

#### Tailwind Work around:

Use `contenteditable` prop of `div` and use `break-words` property

#### Code:

```
<div class="m-4 max-w-full overflow-y-hidden break-words border border-solid border-black text-4xl" contenteditable="true"></div>
```

#### Output:

[image]

#### Like : [`Tailwind Play`](https://play.tailwindcss.com/wLxDXIsqGJ)